# How to convert location data to longitude and altitude using the query of PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, converters, latitude-longitude, altitude

I am newbie to PostgreSQL and postGIS...I have a PostgreSQL database dump, which contains a series of location data.

The location data should be the longitude and altitude of some points but is stored in the sql file in a string of numbers and letters, which is odd for me. For instance:

> 0101000020E61000009513A7B4801F6340131CD8D0766A3BC0

How I can convert this string to longitude and altitude using the query of PostgreSQL?

Comment: So, the problem is that you don't know what format your source data is in?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a postgis extension and than you can cast geography-location to geometry and use ST_AsLatLonText(geometry) function.

```
SELECT ST_AsLatLonText
FROM (0101000020E61000009513A7B4801F6340131CD8D0766A3BC0::geometry);
```